# How to build a slider just like on Google search results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Really want to know how I can achieve similar result that you sometimes see displaying on search results when you google things like points of interest for a location.

For example like here: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=los+angeles+points+of+interest

Comment: You can google 'Jquery sliders'

Comment: This isn't  resource recommendation service and requests like this are off-topic